# Error while trying to write in Azure Tables ('' is not a valid value for a partition key or row key)

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am a beginner in Azure. I'm trying to add a row in Azure Tables  storage using Python.
I followed the simple example of Microsoft documentation :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-output?tabs=in-process%2Cstorage-extension&pivots=programming-language-python#example

However, I get this error : *Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables: '' is not a valid value
for a partition key or row key* and I don't see the table created in my MicrosoftAzure Storage Explorer.

I already have a functional  azure function with a **queueTrigger** as an input binding. So, I added an **ouptut binding** Table in the configuration file "function.json":

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
     {
      "name": "dataSetId",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "local-toprep",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
     },
     {
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "message",
      "tableName": "messages",
      "partitionKey": "message",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
     }
   ]
}
```

And in my main function ,I added my table "message" in the arguments and I added those lines :

```
rowKey = str(uuid.uuid4())
data = {
         "Name": "Output binding message",
         "PartitionKey": "message",
         "RowKey": rowKey
        }
message.set(json.dumps(data))
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: The same problem today with NodeJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, my problem was in host.js file.
Azure table works only in version 2.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just saw the note  in the documentation : "Version 3.x of the extension bundle currently does not include the Table Storage bindings. If your app requires Table Storage, you will need to continue using the 2.x version for now.". So, I updated the version of the bundle extention v2 and it worked !! 

Nothe that the text of the error mentionned in the terminal had nothing to do with the real problem.

Comment: This fixed the problem I was seeing. Simply changing from 3.x to 2.x and 4.0.0 to 3.0.0 solved it.  Thanks!!!

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.login. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables: Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsStorage' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.

Comment: January 2023 and developing with Powershell to write to Azure tables and the template still has the same issue. Updated to version 2 and it works.

Comment: September 2023 and doing Azure Durable Function also have the same issue, host.json for NET 6 + Azure Function 4.x with Azure Durable function doesn't seems to support setting extension bundle version...somehow hacked it by setting the TableOutput includes RowKey directly which should not be needed as they are already part of response